# How to get MSBUILD to use a specific PublishProfile for VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

This question has been asked a lot, and to compound matters over several versions of Visual Studio.  What I have done so far is:

1. Create a new Web Application in Visual Studio 2013
2. Created 3 "publish" profiles.  **Web** publishes to my local IIS, **DEBUG** and **RELEASE** both do a "file copy" to c:\temp\debug and c:\temp\release respectively

All three profiles work from the IDE.  The problem comes when I try to use **MSBUILD** and use the **/p:PublishProfile** option.  I have tried dozens of options but none of them seem to call the profile I specify.  I would think it should be as simple as calling:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=RELEASE
```

Yet that complains about not having the Configuration and CPU type set (even though that is specified in the profile).  If I go ahead and add those to the command line, I usually end up getting:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project

I've tried using **/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0** and **/p:Configuration=XXX** (even though THAT is set in the profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the below given command:

**msbuild "path\to\projectFlie\xyz.csproj" /t:Publish /p:configuration=Release-Prod /p:PublishDir="C:\temp"**

If it complains about OutputPath property for a project, do the following:

1. Go to the **.csproj** file of the project that is throwing an error.
2. Find Property group for the particular configuration. A property group should look like this:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-Prod|AnyCPU' ">
   <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
   <Optimize>true</Optimize>
   <OutputPath>bin\Release-Prod\</OutputPath>
   <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
   <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
   <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
   <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
   <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

Make sure that the name in **OutputPath** (Release-Prod) exactly matches the **configuration** name.

#### If you don't find a property group for your configuration, add one.

This should fix your problem.